# Catch errors of HttpUrlConnection in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I'm searching for a best practice to handle errors in an HttpURLConnection especially if the host is not available. How did I have to change my source?:

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    URL aURL;
    String line;
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    BufferedReader reader;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
    try {
        aURL = new URL(strings[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) aURL.openConnection();


        InputStream aInputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream aBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(aInputStream);

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("svc", e.toString());
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Well, the exception is caught - what do you *want* to happen?

Comment: since you don't initially allocate `stringBuilder`, IF you have an exception then you are going to have trouble on `return stringBuilder.toString();` (NullPointerException, i think)

Comment: Hi, I want to return the result - ok I can do this via teh return statement, but what's more important for me: How do I catch exceptions which are thrown by the connection (connection = (HttpURLConnection) aURL.openConnection();), or is the one catch block enough to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will get different responsecode using connection.getResponseCode()
Check for the response codes for host not available and you will be set.

Comment: But what happens if the server is not available (unstable network). What is the result of getResponseCode() in this case?

Comment: something other than `HttpStatus.SC_OK`